# Perl Access Global arrays

Tags: perl

I have classA and I define a global array in classA

```
our @myArray = {"1","2","3","4"}
```

I have classB in which I have a object of classA. I tried accessing myArray as follows.

```
$my_obj_of_classA->{'myArray'} 
$my_obj_of_classA->{'\@myArray'} 
$my_obj_of_classA->{\@myArray}
```

None of these work. I get an error saying:

> Global symbol "@my_array" requires explicit package name

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: `use strict;`, `use warnings;` and try to write something that at least *looks* like Perl.

Comment: Step away from the global state, and start passing parameters.

Comment: I am getting the error because I use strict in my code. I have updated the question. I understand passing parameters is better, but can you help me with passing global array as a parameter.

Comment: I get this \Global symbol "@my_array" requires explicit package name

Comment: And when I google this error, I see that perl wants variables to be defined before use. Clearly my syntax to access the global array is incorrect, because I have defined it in classA

Comment: This question contains a deep misunderstanding of how global variables and objects work in Perl. It looks like you're expecting `@myArray` to act something like a class variable in Ruby in that you can access it on any given object of that class. That is not how globals in Perl work at all. I could answer your question, but you'll just run afoul of another misunderstanding. I think it best if you backed up and at least skimmed Perl from the start. Reviewing [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

First off, this:

```
package classA;
...
our @myArray = {"1","2","3","4"}
```

declares a package (sometimes called global) variable @classA::myArray, containing a single element whose value is a hashref.  I suspect you meant this instead:

```
our @myArray = ("1","2","3","4");
```

Secondly, you can just access that array from any other package by fully qualifying it as `@classA::myArray`.  Perl does not provide automatically available class or object methods for interacting with global variables.  If you want, you can create one in your classA as simply as saying:

```
sub myArray { \@myArray }
```

if you want it to get a reference to the array or

```
sub myArray { @myArray }
```

if you want it (in list context) to get the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `@my_array` is not defined as a global variable.  Since you haven't posted your actual code, I can't provide more information than that.  Of course, this isn't really providing any information at all, either, since it's just telling you exactly what the error message told you.

If you improve your question, I'll improve my answer.

Comment: What information do you need. Please let me know. Is my declaration of array incorrect, is the way I access it incorrect. What is it? How does providing the logic of my code help in this scenario.